# What's "result in crunch at the end to meet our deadline"

Tags: phrase-meaning

I got a feedback on a project like this

> As a result, Project xxx faced a number of issues from the xxx team
> which resulted in a crunch at the end to meet our deadline.

I'm struggling to understand what "***result in a crunch at the end to meet our deadline***". Can someone help?

Comment: This is corporate code for "The xxx team messed up and caused your project to work overtime (resulted in a crunch) to make the deadline."

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=crunch) records among other meanings of ***crunch*** as a noun:

> A critical moment or situation, especially one that occurs because of a *shortage of **time** or resources*:
>
> - a year-end crunch; an energy crunch.

So that particular team raised some issues with that Project and that provoked a *crunch*, a time crisis. These issues delayed them and they barely made it for the deadline.